# How to disable 3 buttons once one of them is clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here are the buttons in the output:

[image]

and here are the same buttons in the code that I want to disable after one of them is clicked once:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Menu du jeu")
root.geometry("600x300")
root.config(bg="#7f7f7f")


b1 = Button(root, text="Facile", fg='white', bg="black", command=lambda: [commencerJeu1(), root.destroy()])

b1.pack(side="left", ipadx=10, ipady=10)



b2 = Button(root, text="Moyen", fg='blue', bg="black", command=lambda: [commencerJeu2(), root.destroy()])
b2.pack(side="left", ipadx=10, ipady=10)

b3 = Button(root, text="Difficile", fg='orange', bg="black", command=lambda: [commencerJeu3(), root.destroy()])
b3.pack(side="left", ipadx=10, ipady=10)

b4 = Button(root, text="fermer", fg='yellow', bg="black", command=root.destroy)
b4.pack(side="right", ipadx=10, ipady=10)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: To disable a button you can use the `state` config parameter `b1.config(state='disabled')`.  To re-enable a button `b1.config(state='normal')`.

Comment: i want if possible after one click at b1 . All of b1 and b2 and b3 gets disabled at the same time

Comment: create a button callback (command parameter) that calls `b.config(state='disabled')` for each button.